# Android: How to make List<List<String>> parcelable in a model

Tags: android

I have a model `User implements Parcelable` which contains a field `List<List<String>> segments`. How to read and write this type of data in Parcel ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this in my constructor

```
segments = in.readArrayList(FlightSegment.class.getClassLoader());
```

and this below code in `writeToParcel`

```
dest.writeList(segments);
```

Data is passing successfully now.